# Use directive data in component (HTML) in angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5, angular2-directives

I am using directive named ***blue*** where I have a variable named ***count***. I want to use this count variable in the HTML. How can I do this ?
I want something just like below......

```
<div blue >
{{count}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit difficult to answer, as there is a lot of Angular knowledge necessary.

But still, to give you some help, there is a good book on Angular from the publisher Springer. It's called `Pro Angular - Second Edition` and the writer is Adam Freeman. It goes into a lot of detail and also explains everything on directives.

I a try to give you anwer to your question here, I believe yours might look like this:

```
<div class="blue">
    {{count}}
</div>
```

You can either fill the `count` variable within the Angular template or from the Angular model. The model in Angular is typically done using TypeScript. Somewhere within that may be a public variable called `count` or a method called `getCount()` returning a string.

Check out the mentioned book, as it explains it all.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 5, you probably are looking for a component where you can define properties.

```
<blue>{{count}}</blue>
```

https://angular.io/guide/quickstart#first-component, step 4, `title` in component `AppComponent`.

Directive is normally used to decorate the behavior, https://angular.io/api/core/Directive. Normally I don't think `count` belongs to `blue` directive

```
<div blue>{{count}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you might need Output events. Just add `@Output() count = new EventEmitter<number>();` in your directive and use it like this:

***component.html***

```
<div blue (count)="changeCount($event)">
  {{count}}
</div>
```

***component.ts***

```
count: number;
changeCount(event: number) {
  this.count = event;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to revisit the logic of directive.
for detail this link will help you in detail
https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives

Answer (score 0):

You could use output events as LordAlpaca mentioned, or you could pass in an instance of your parent component and have the attribute directive set the count value on your parent component:

Template:

```
<h1 [blue]="appComponent">
     {{count}}
</h1>
```

AppComponent

```
export class AppComponent {
    count : number;
    appComponent = this;
}
```

Directive

```
export class BlueDirective implements OnInit{
  count : number = 4;
  @Input("blue") component : any;

  ngOnInit(){
    this.component.count = this.count;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using template var.
In your directive:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[appBlue]',
    exportAs: 'blueDirective'
})
export class BlueDirective {
    public count: number;
    // your logic here...
}
```

Implementation looks like this:

```
<div appBlue #blue="blueDirective">
    {{ blue.count }}
</div>
```

I hope it can help